# IntelliJ-IDEA Eclipse Ctrl+O equivalent that is better than Alt+7

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

In `Eclipse` I could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and get a popup which I could use to get an overview of everything in the current class, pick an entry, and jump to it.

In `idea`, there is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, but I have a few issues with it. First, the keyboard doesn't seem to put its focus there. I have to take my hand off the keyboard and use the mouse to place the focus on the Structure dock.
I also don't like how it's taking up real estate. I don't want to change how things are laid out if I want to see the structure. I would like a more non-invasive popup, and handier and snappier.

Is there another feature that gives me quick access in the form of a popup preferably, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> provides in `Eclipse`?

Another nice feature would be to be able to use the <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> keys to move up and down the selection, instead of having to use the cursor keys. I'm using `IdeaVim`, so the normal workflow when editing files, is that both hands stay in a touch-type position. It would be nice if I can use the various navigation features also using vim keys...
Perhaps there is a way to enable this, that I haven't discovered yet?

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ equivalent of Eclipse's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on Mac), which will give you more or less the same pop-up as in Eclipse. But I'm not sure if it can be navigated using j and k keys.

More details can be found in the [IntelliJ help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-with-structure-views.html).

Comment: Turns out my Window Manager on Xubuntu was taking possession of a bunch of shortcut keys, with Ctrl+F12 being mapped to jump to a workspace (that I don't have, so it did nothing, which made me think that Ctrl-F12 was replaced with Alt+7). Unmapping that, made Ctrl+F12 work.